# Did I lie on my resume by not mentioning I didn't complete my degree?

Tags: communication, resume, job-search, education

On my resume I list my education under a section called "education". I do not mention the word "qualification" and I do not mention my grades.

I list them in the following format: **Course** - **Institution** - **Year From** / **Year To**

For Example:

- BSc Engineering | University of x | 2000 to 2002
- LPIC-2 Linux Engineer | Linux Professional Institute | 2010 - 2011

In the list I have included my time at Uni however, I dropped out after 2 years. Originally I put a description saying I had completed 2 years with top marks however I removed the descriptions to make space for my job experience.

In my mind this is perfectly fine. I am listing the time I have spent in education, not the qualifications and grades I have received.

In my last job they asked about the degree during the interview, and I didn't mind explaining why I had dropped out. My intention was never to be misleading.

Recently I changed jobs, and I think my employer has assumed I have a degree as he didn't ask me about my education during the interview.

**My question here is:** is my resume misleading, and could this be seen as a lie?

*I am not asking what I should do about it.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103668/discussion-on-question-by-flexi-did-i-lie-on-my-resume).

Comment: I've been working as a software engineer with no degree for the last 5 years. On my CV I have stated that I was in the Uni from 2010 to 2014 and also I did and exchange year from 2014 to 2015. I did not finish my degree because of the expensive taxes, and I actually started working as a software engineer on the 2015 summer. I am not writing I dropped out Uni or anything. During the interviews I have I always tell my story and why I did not finish. Most of the interviews well okay and they verify my knowledge with programming problems.Now, I am doing a MSc to supply the lack of degree.

Comment: @flexi, Can you write something like this on your resume "Computer Science -University of x | 2000 to 2002 - INCOMPLETE" (if you quit school a long time ago)   or "Computer Science | University of x | 2000 to 2002 - IN PROGRESS" (if you are still taking classes on-and-off.) ... ?

Answer (score 89):

**People who make sloppy assumptions have only themselves to blame**

Putting "dropped out" or "incomplete" beside your education would be like putting "terminated" beside past jobs where your contract was not renewed or you got fired. Nobody would advise doing that.

Employers would love to know if you have a criminal record, but nobody would advise putting "convicted felon" on one's resume because you are otherwise allowing your employer to assume you are not.

A resume is a marketing document that consists of factual information. It is not a factual assessment of your career. It is certainly not unbiased. It is instead the bullish case for you.

I don't see how clarifying beforehand is better than having to explain in an interview or after getting hired. In both cases, they are far more invested in you and the cost of removing you from consideration is higher. In both cases, they are forced to at least listen to your explanation. Many people would have a hard time admitting they misread and would instead find other reasons to justify your candidacy (a decent story there). At the resume state, they can just go "next please" in 10 seconds.

Leave it as is. It can only benefit you if people are sloppy in their thinking and assessment.

Comment: This viewpoint is understood by employers as well. It's just like if you are a new graduate with a bad GPA: you don't put it on your resume because it will make you look bad. If an employer is looking for the GPA, they'll assume it's bad because you didn't list it, but you don't want to proactively call attention to the fact that you had a low GPA.

Comment: One caveat: you should never omit information with the intent to deceive.  For example, if the job strictly required a degree and you did this hoping the interviewer would just *assume* you had one, then many would consider it as bad as if you outright lied. If on the other hand a degree is not required, then it's not relevant to your qualifications and there's nothing wrong with leaving it off.

Comment: @bta Over here a lot of jobs 'require' degrees that the final applicants don't have. If they ask for a Uni degree, they'll often take a Bsc. If they ask for a Bsc, a drop-out with field experience will also get the job. So it's not as black&white as that. Assumptions are *their* problem. Just don't lie, and if asked whether you got the degree while you didn't, say you don't. That's it.

Comment: @Mast I don't know where your "over here" is, but over **here,** a BSc *is* a university degree, most now requiring four years' study after finishing tertiary education (ie, from age 18).

Comment: I actually did include something to the effect of "Post graduate coursework" on my resume to indicate time spent working on a PhD that I never finished. So there should be a way to word this that is clear and not as bad as "dropped out". Someone could see two years at a university as "I graduated in just two years" which makes the person look like a rockstar.

Comment: Regarding the key premise to this answer, it takes two to communicate, and *both* parties share responsibility for understanding. It doesn't just lie with the person receiving the communications. Someone can definitely lie by wording things in a way that while technically correct, they have strong reason to believe will be misinterpreted by the recipient to the advantage of the sender. So I disagree with this answer. Ethically and professionally you do have to take into account possible misunderstandings about how you word things.

Comment: @Andrew In Europe with bologna a bachelor now usually is supposed to take 3 years of study, but generally there's nothing stopping people from taking additional courses and finishing early (this is not even particularly unrealistic, you can often get the introduction courses waived when coming from the right school). So the assumption "I only studied there for 2 years, not enough to qualify for a degree" definitely does not hold here. I didn't pay that close attention when studying in the US, but it didn't seem like there was anything stopping me from taking more courses either.

Comment: @Voo this is also true in the US.  it is very common to transfer or have high school credits, as well as summer classes that have people graduate in 2 years.  Likewise US has associates degrees that can count towards a different school bachelors degree.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You can find my 'over here' conveniently located in my profile. And 'over here'  most places you can get a BSc from are not called university in Dutch but 'Hogeschool' while inconveniently both 'Universiteit' and 'Hogeschool' are translated to university. What we call here a university gets you an MSc. So, you're right but that's where the confusion comes from. A BSc university should be better translated as college IMO.

Comment: "Leave it as is. It can only benefit you if people are sloppy in their thinking and assessment." Except by the people who will look at it, see that it's two years - too short to complete it, and yet it's not annotated at so, which means it will be binned as dishonest, where otherwise it would probably not be a big deal at all. Lie by omission is a thing.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I'm not trying to adjust anything. I'm telling he's right and where the confusion came from, nothing more.

Comment: I don't agree with "leave it as is". I'm a fellow University drop out, and I make this clear on my CV as I genuinely worry about misleading people. It hasn't affected my career, I think people appreciate the honesty.

Comment: @Mast most job descriptions aren't requirement lists, so of course often enough people without a degree will get the job where ' the *ideal* candidate has 5 degrees, is 20 years, does para gliding and has no mum'. But if you come with an attitude of 'I'll give them the best misleading story in which I shine and if they don't see through all the grey lies it's their fault', I'll mostly take any other person with *some* technical competency over you, because I don't want to work with someone I need to double check each and every task to see whether they did it correct or technically correct..

Comment: @FrankHopkins Nobody lied here and nobody was misleading on purpose. If a degree is required, they should ask whether one has at the interview, just like every important part of the resume should be checked at the interview. After all, it's an incomplete summary. You want a bigger, clearer picture of who you're hiring. If the interviewer isn't asking good questions, that's not the fault of the recruit. Whenever asked about it, always answer truthfully. Doesn't mean you have to focus on it. If they're stupid enough to make assumptions, that's their problem. You need better interviewers.

Comment: Since this argues about the investment cost, I'd like to point out one huge error in the reasoning: The interview process is designed to spend money to filter out good fits. Companies are planning that investment so no matter how much money it cost to get you to some step in the process that money is already budgeted - and there are alternative candidates. If the company finds out at that stage that the candidate cost them money by being dishonest or simply providing information in a sloppy way, that is a good indication that the candidate isn't an economoically sound investment.

Comment: If you uncover lies, dishonesty or playing the rules that early, then it's probable more is to come. So other candidates might be preferable - unless you look for someone who likes to play the rules.

Comment: @Mast As for the lying part, that is questionable and depends a bit on the convention in the field/area of OP. In my area, I'd consider it a lie or a very blatant misdirection (see my answer). The point however is, you don't make a good impression by playing the "if they're too stupid to look through my charade" game. That attitude shows that you know you're hiding something by being intentionally unclear, even if that is not lawfully enforceable, it's morally clearly dishonesty that you just rationalize in front of yourself.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Misleading on purpose is a different ballgame alltogether. That wasn't in question here.

Comment: The item as written tells most people that you got the degree in that year.  So a counter-question might be “did you know that what you wrote would make people think something false?”

Answer (score 35):

This is somewhat location specific, but also depends on what you refer to as "Course".  If you are referring to a class you took at an institute, like:

> CS 101, University of Stack Exchange, 2019-2021

then no this would not be lying at all.

If you are referring to a degree program, such as:

> Bachelor of Science, University of Stack Exchange, 2019-2021

Then yes, you would be intentionally misleading on your resume. The standard title of "Education" is referring to a degree, the Bachelor of Science, that being on your resume claims you earned this.  If someone had two years on a resume and applied to a position under me, I would be more inclined to assume they graduated early with credits transferring from high school than assuming they put a degree on their resume that they did not earn.

I would be hard pressed to find someone claiming this latter example is not a problem and someone is being sloppy for assuming it means that you had a degree. The case in which it would be considered sloppy is if a company requires degrees and never asks the question on a form or does a background check.

Comment: I like the point you made about transfer credits. It's not rare at all for someone to transfer and get a degree from a university after two years. In fact, I'd guess that's much more common than listing unfinished degrees in the education section of a resume.

Comment: *Course - Institution - Year* is ok.  *Degree - Institution - Year*... IS NOT, +1

Answer (score 25):

> is my resume misleading?

Let me ask another question: Why are you not simply marking the education entry as "*not completed*"? That would remove all ambiguity. But unless you haven't thought of this option, maybe this ambiguity is strategic.

You can foresee that this, potentially, may give the false impression that you completed the education. This is, by definition, misleading. If it comes up at a later stage, the obvious defense is that "you were just stating the facts".

You have to answer for yourself if you think you get away with it, if you willing to take this risk, and if it is ethical.

Comment: my intention wasn't to be misleading, but I don't want to list "not complete" because to me that makes no sense. On the others I would then have to put "complete" to be consistent which takes up too much room. I thought calling it education rather than qualifications was the best solution. To me that is transparent and very clear, but I am now doubting if others have the same logic as myself.

If I had called them qualifications, then I agree with mentioning it's not complete.

Comment: @flexi `On the others I would then have to put "complete" to be consistent` Do you really believe that? It's only the incomplete education that's ambiguous and needs clarification.

Comment: yes, to me all entries should have the same layout or it looks messy. I initially had a description for it but needed to remove it to keep on 2 pages. Maybe I just need to accept I need 3 pages now, or just remove my education now as it's almost irrelevant compared to my experience.

Comment: @flexi Up to you what you do, but my thought is, if I'd ask you why you didn't mention the incomplete education, and the response was that you thought the resume layout looked better without that information, I'd probably not buy that explanation

Comment: My explanation would be, I listed my time in education and completed 2 years of it.
But I think ultimately you are right, and I probably should include something to say the actual qualification was incomplete.

Comment: @ig-dev Of course they don't. They know what they're doing and know what answer they want. Anything outside that may as well be white noise.

Comment: Learning is a lifelong task.  Consider "not yet completed" as a slightly positive take.

Comment: I do this on my resume. I went to university for 4 years, but then dropped out. I list the years I attended and what I studied. I've only once been asked something about graduation, and I honestly responded that I did not graduate. I don't feel it's unethical since I don't list that I have a Bachelor's or that I graduated, and I do want to reflect that I went to four years of university, but some interviewers might not take it that way.

Comment: @flexi Perhaps a word like "partial" has less negative connotations that "incomplete"?

Answer (score 11):

> **Did I Lie on my resume?**

Yes, No, Maybe.

The actual question you should be asking is: Was the information I provided in my CV is easily understood?

The answer is : No.

CV is not the place to create or leave room for confusion / misunderstanding / interpretation. You should be as precise and correct as possible.

> *I list them in the following format: Course - Institution - Year From / Year To*

and

> *....It clearly shows I only studied there for 2 years, not enough to qualify for a degree.*

If you're using something like "2012-2014" as "From" and "To" respectively, it may create confusion, as not everyone will know whether the course was supposed to be of 2-years duration or, you did not finish the course.

So, instead of putting two years as start and end, put the start year in "Year From", and under "Year to", mention *"incomplete"*.

This way, you're communicating the fact that the education (degree) was incomplete.

Comment: Some people use the terms "resume" and "cv" interchangeably, but they do have differing definitions. It seems like your answer here is for a CV, and in that regard it's a good answer. But the OP did use the word "resume" a few times, so I'm assuming that's what they meant.

Comment: "2012-2014" implies a full 3 years
Edit: forgot some countries start and end mid year

Comment: @fjw Yes, in my country it's mid year, so habituated to see and write like that.

Comment: @fjw My country starts and ends mid-year, and I wouldn't know whether this is 2 years or 3. And I definitely know people who have gotten a 4 year degree in 3. Hell, I'm one of them.

Answer (score 10):

> It clearly shows I only studied there for 2 years, not enough to qualify for a degree.

That sounds a lot like "not lying" to me.

Your resume is clearly slanted in your favor, but that's normal.  A better question to ask is

*"if your employer later discovers that you don't have a degree, will that be a problem?"*

As long as you're clearly doing your job well and there aren't outside requirements<sup>1</sup> for a degree, you'll be fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some contracts between businesses may specify that all people working on a project hold a certain degree or certification.  Since you didn't mention that in your question, I assume it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @DJClayworth Unless I misread the question, the OP is well past the recruiting stage and already has the job.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right.

Comment: yes, already have the job. I doubt the employer would actually mind. I was just wondering about it.

Comment: It could also be read as being so good you only needed two years to complete a degree.

Comment: how is the normal conclusion from a time to "oh he dropped out" instead of "oh he's excellent and was fast"? Given that OP displays the title the normal *convention* is that this means he got the title.

Answer (score 5):

**You were at the very least misleading**. At least once you've started to question yourself, you'd be at least borderline lying and after reading this answer intentionally misleading (with a possible way out).

**If this came up in an interview I'd (likely) reject you for being dishonest or at the very least unprepared and unclear in your communication.** At the least it would be a big negative point on the character assessment side. I don't need a colleague who is not aware of typical convention in important communication or even worse who intentionally tries to play the rules by *strictly technically* not breaking them. Then again, perhaps for some professions that's a plus point...

Why is that:
In all environments I've worked so far, any degree listed on a CV under education is by convention a degree the candidate claims to hold. If that is not the case that needs to be marked. Since you wrote

> - BSc Engineering | University of x | 2000 to 2002
> - LPIC-2 Linux Engineer | Linux Professional Institute | 2010 - 2011

That refers to a degree, namely a BSc. The time is irrelevant, there are enough ways and places where one could get a Bsc in that time (and one can also easily read that as 3 years). If that seemed a short time, the natural assumption would be that you were excellent and finished really fast or perhaps that there was some special arrangement at play. (It would be different if you listed individual courses without an associated degree.)

Now, if the normal convention in your location area differs from what would be considered standard in my typical environment, you might be fine, but you should make sure that others in that environment really read this explicitly as "time spent towards" instead of "education with degree received".

If you don't know the normal convention, morally you can claim ignorance - which from now on you cannot having read this answer.

*The general underlying issue:*

The underlying issue is that this a 'special' case in a sea of 'normal' cases. You generally have two options: you try to hide the fact that it's unfinished or you point it out such that it is crystal clear. I'd personally always prefer an honest factual approach. If you try to hide it, maybe it's overlooked and people hire you assuming the wrong thing - perhaps it's overlooked forever or it creates bad blood later. If it comes up at the interview stage it's likely that it will have worse repercussions than if it was clear from the beginning (especially if you can show that you did good in the time you spent there).

You can still make it sound as good as possible: For instance, psychologically one might argue that "unfinished" has negative side-connotations, which is why I suggest a more factual approach, e.g. writing "(2 of X years)" next to it possibly combined with a "Studies towards" prefix or something similar. If you have good grades, point to them being attached if that is possible. This is all less of an issue as well if you can provide a cover letter in addition, where in one side note you can explain that while you did good, it wasn't your thing but that other interesting stuff got a hold of you. Topic covered, there are plenty of successful smart dropouts.

Again, in some places the convention might not be in place or not as strongly. I'd still argue that clarity is always beneficial as negative surprises in or after the interview process are most of the time not worth it, but the less the convention is common, the less it's a moral lying issue and more an issue of (wilful) unclarity or (if the convention is strictly time spent) adhering to the convention and not providing more information than necessary.

The more actual job experience you have the less important a degree anyway, but feeling misled or being lied to might be a showstopper.

Comment: If all I did was remove the "Bsc", do you think that would be enough, or still misleading?

Comment: @flexi it would stand out more, but it'd still be an oddball that can get you in the situation that an interviewer with good enough reason assumes you got some university degree and then finds out you didn't at some stage in the interview process or after. (Btw. I guess you did finish that LPIC-2 certification? Which would mean different things are lumped together and thus more likely to create a misreading.). "Studies towards a BSc Engineering" would be the most brushing it up attempt that I'd find acceptable. You could also go with (2 of X years) or ~ percent etc.

Comment: @flexi The main point is, you have two options: you try to hide the fact that it's unfinished or you point it out such that it is crystal clear. I'd personally always prefer an honest factual approach. If you try to hide it, maybe it's overlooked and people hire you assuming the wrong thing - perhaps it's overlooked forever or it creates bad blood later. If it comes up at the interview stage it's likely that it will have worse repercussions than if it was clear from the beginning (especially if you can show that you did good in the time you spent there).

Comment: @flexi You can still make it sound as good as possible: For instance, psychologically one might argue that "unfinished" has negative side-connotations, which is why I suggest the more factual 2 years of X way to make it clear. Or if you have good grades, point to them being attached if that is possible. This is all less of an issue as well if you can provide a cover letter as well, where in one side note you can explain that while you did good, it wasn't your thing but that other interesting stuff got a hold of you. Topic covered, there are plenty of successfull smart dropouts.

Comment: I want to make it clear but also don't want to draw focus on it. I like the 2 of x years approach. That works really well. I am also considering removing my education section completely as I have over 12 years working in the industry which I think has far more value than my time at university.

Comment: @flexi Yes for most cases after so many years in the area the work experience is way more important as a door opener and the education is more of a background information helping to round the picture (i.e. can you also understand theory, successfully completed several courses might be good enough of an indication if your previous jobs don't cover that anyway). The jobs were it still would be strictly relevant are those where people explicitly look for someone with a degree (e.g. for regulation reasons) - in that case it's imho way better (saves everyone time) if they find out quickly.

Answer (score 1):

> My question here is: is my resume misleading, and would this be seen as a lie?

It is currently up to interpretation.  It is better that you clarify on your resume, so that there is no room for anyone to guess.  If you are applying for a company that requires a degree then you will likely be asked for a transcript or other proof at some point in the hiring process.  It is better for the company to know up front that you have no degree than for you having to explain later in the process ( or even after being hired ) why you do not have a degree.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation with my resume.

I put both of my times in college on my resume. I unfortunately didn't finish my degree the first time I went and several years later I got a lesser degree at a smaller college. I don't put on my resume that I didn't finish the first degree, I simply state when I attended the university.

What usually happens is that I get a few questions about it during the interview. This is when questions are supposed to come up. I answer truthfully about not finishing and that's generally the end of things. Most of my interviews end up with a positive success for me.

I'm not lying, even though I put down 4 years for that first entry. The fact that I was only able to take 1 semester, instead of 2, for most of those years is completely irrelevant, and the few questions that come up about my education clear up any ambiguity that my resume has for the interviewer.

Unless asked, your GPA, grades, individual courses, and all of that is irrelevant. If you are beyond the first 2-3 years after college, they won't really matter. Since you already have had another job, your new employer assumes that you did the job reasonably well and you didn't fail all of your classes. The employer likely verified your previous job and that you went to school when you said you did. If they did their job correctly, they should also have verified whether you have a degree when they verified your time at the school.

In my experience, there's always ambiguity in resumes. Many people list things they only did for a few months while other items they did for years are left out. This is the nature of selling yourself for the job you want. Yes, education can be a bit tricky this way, but you still have the experience of going to college and the education of the courses you took. Degrading that by putting "Did not finish" on your resume is like putting a "Please ignore me" stamp on it instead. Recruiters and hiring managers are looking for any obvious sign on your resume to pitch it, and that's one of them. You'd have to have massive experience in exactly what they need before they would reconsider tossing a resume with that kind of mark on it.

A resume/CV is your calling card, your advertisement of yourself. Car manufacturers don't put recall warnings in their TV ads. Pet food companies don't list all the allergenic complications a pet can have with their food. Computer manufacturers don't tell you how many times their hardware dies in their ads. Phone companies don't tell you how often the battery explodes in their devices. The only people required to list this type of thing in their advertisements are medically related items, like medicines and implants, due to the extreme nature of the reactions that can happen. You aren't required to tell people why you shouldn't be hired. If people were, there'd be a lot more positions available.

Answer (score 1):

Did you lie? No. Were you misleading? Somewhat. Is what you did going to be a problem? Probably not, but it depends entirely on the employer and industry you're in. There's not a definitive answer, it's all about your circumstances.

In my industry (software) you'd be fine. You have previous experience and the hired you on that. No one cares where you went to school once you're hired and no one is ever likely to check anyway. The only way this could ever be a concern is if they have you slotted into a pay grade based on (perceived) completed education; some places do operate that way. If so I'd never bring this up - if they never check into it, congratulations on your (slightly) improved salary; if they do, remind them that the resume never mentioned a degree and no one ever asked. If they then try to cut or freeze your salary, improve your resume (perhaps err on the side of honesty this time) and move on.

Bottom line, in at least my industry, employers are all about two things: can you get the work done and do you cause trouble. If the former is yes and you don't make trouble for someone by mentioning your lack of a degree, you're fine. If the degree matters (for salary, for example) you'll only make someone else look bad by bringing up the fact that they didn't ask the right questions. Don't do that. No one wins.

But in some professions, education is a very big deal. If you're going for a teaching position in the USA and they even think you mislead them about your qualifications, you'll likely be unemployed in short order. The fact that someone didn't do due diligence on your resume won't matter.

On balance, you didn't lie in a technical sense but if a misunderstanding happened it would likely be seen as your fault, you sly dog. But if your work is good, it shouldn't matter. If you're happy and they're happy, leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

**You might, but it is part of the double standard surrounding educational experience vs other experience. Leave it be.**

Would you put when you cost your company $250,000 because of a mistake on your resume? **No.** Even if it caused them to think that everything went perfectly at your job? Still no.

Would you put that you have a criminal record on your resume? **No.** Even if it caused your boss to think that you are record free? Still no.

Would you put that you cheated on exams to get your degree? **No.** Even if your employer wanted to know that? No. [And most people cheat in university.](https://www.cleveland.com/metro/2017/02/cheating_in_college_has_become.html)

Would you put that you were fired on your resume? **No.** Even though your employer would definitely want to know what? Still no.

Would you put that you had a low GPA on your resume? **No.** Even if you had a pile of academic awards in a few courses which might mislead them? Still no.

I cannot think of a case where someone would actively point out a negative on their resume.

The majority of answerers here would not advise people to reveal any of these things on a resume and to let people overlook it because they will assume things which are not stated.

**Let that work in your favor. Everyone lets that happen with everything else.**

Why is everyone in a huff about it? Because they have degrees (as do I) and view education as this pure thing to be protected from any taint even if it screws certain lessers over.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your CV is going to be read, and bear in mind that it can be read many years from now.

In Colombia some politicians had in their CVs information about education that was only misleading (as yours). They *didn't actually claimed to be a doctor*, but they reported in their education dates and institutions for doctorate studies. Notable cases, among many others, are [Bogota's former mayor](https://en.m.wikinews.org/wiki/Major_Colombian_newspaper_reveals_Bogot%C3%A1_mayor_does_not_hold_claimed_PhD_degree) and even the [actual president](https://colombiareports.com/duke-ivan-and-his-shrinking-cv/).

So not being clear about your academic achievements may not be, strictly speaking, lying; but that ambiguity may come later in life to haunt you.